# Visual Studio 2008: .pdb files not created by "Build Solution"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution containing a number of C++ projects.  When I select the Debug configuration, and build each project individually, I find .pdb files for each project in the Debug directory.  But when I build the entire solution, I don't.  The output files show up in the Debug directory, but the .pdb files are missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: So could you please post the build output after setting verbosity to *diagnostic*?

Answer (score 8):

Look at Project Properties > Compile - Press Advance Compile Options then new Window will open, find Generate debug info and you can choose None, pdb - only, or full - if none then that would be the reason why you don't have pdb

Answer (score 5):

Building the entire solution indeed builds the individual projects (in parallel, if possible). The project configuration being built is specified in the [Configuration Manager Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz.aspx). This also specifies if a project is built at all, or if it will be excluded from the build in that solution configuration.

So, if your PDBs aren't showing up, double-check that your projects are being built (you seem to say so, but just to be sure, delete all the intermediate and output folders, and build the solution again). Also check what project configurations are being assigned to each solution configuration. Maybe your `Debug` solution config actually references some `Release` project configs (or `Debug_but_no_pdb`).

If this still doesn't help, enable verbose output for the build process:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity: Diagnostic

Also, double-check all project dependencies for invalid references.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a lot about your project you don't tell us here.  However, this reference might offer some hints:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx

Based on this, I notice that since the pdb is for incremental linking, perhaps the compiler feels it doesn't need them since it is doing the final linking as part of the build.

Additionally, since the EXE path is one of the places the PDBs are looked for . . . any chance they are in that directory instead?

Comment: It was my understanding that all of the configuration about how a project is built is stored in the .cs_proj file.  That when you build a solution, msbuild simply builds each project according to the rules specified in each projects' .cs_proj file.  And since the .cs_proj files specify that a .pdb file be built and placed in the same directory as the .exe, I'm at a loss as to why this isn't happening when I build the solution, instead of each project individually.

Comment: @Jeff: your question refers to C++ projects, but this comment refers to C# projects. Are you certain you're dealing with the right build configuration?

Comment: Sorry.  We do a lot of C# and a lot of C++, and I got the extensions confused.  These are .vcproj files.